# How do I apply a graphql-middleware to my Apollo Federation?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

I don’t use the managed Apollo federation instead I have a solution which looks like this:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway: new ApolloGateway({
    
    supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
      subgraphs: [
        // ...
      ],
    }),
    
  }),
});
```

How do I apply a [graphql-middleware](https://github.com/dimatill/graphql-middleware) to my federation GraphQL schema? I’d like to add a middleware which does access control in my gateway server before the request reaches the downstream services.